# VSTS - Use API to get a list of all projects, not just top 100

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops

I am trying to get a complete list of projects in VSTS. Using this code gives me the first 100 projects, but I can find no way to specify/ask for more

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://{accountname}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", {credentials});

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //failed
    }
}

// Convert responseString into a json Object
RootObj jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(responseString);
Console.WriteLine("Found " + jsonObj.Count + " projects");

//Do stuff
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.Value)
{
    //foreach project...
}
```

I know that there are more than 100 projects, but it will only every return that many. Is there some way to incorporate a "TOP 1000" into the request? What would that syntax be? Thanks

---

Works now that I changed one line to read:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?$top=250&stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised the API documentation is incomplete. You can specify a `$top` parameter.

Ex: `_apis/projects?$top=250&version=1.0`

Comment: Sweet! That works perfectly and now I am getting back 108 projects. I will mark this as the answer as soon as the minimum time elapses.

Comment: @Daniel Mann could you please look below question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369690/how-to-get-all-the-files-and-and-directories-in-a-project-and-repository-in-azur )